# Hide elements on Jimdo website using jquery by certain data attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, show-hide, title, webshop

I'm creating a Jimdo Webshop. For the landing page, I would like to hide the nav bar.

I have identified the element's class and can hide it via CSS, but I only want to hide it on one page. As I can only inject code into the header, I need to identify the page by the menu item that is selected.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-link-title="Home" class="active">Home</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I hide the `div` with the class `nav` when the link in the list has the `data-link-title="Home"` and the `class="active"`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do it myself. What I wanted to achieve, was to show the header in fullscreen while hiding all the rest, so as to achieve a landing page. As Jimdo applies one template to all pages, it is not possible to achieve this effect without this solution.

What I did find was a different workaround inserting an `html` widget into the page with an `img` and then style it to be fullscreen and cover up the rest by increasing the `z-index`. I find this quite ugly, as all of the content is still there and basically visible. It also gave strange effects on mobile.

Let me know, if you have a better and/or cleaner solution. Hope this helps someone!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("test")) {
    var theHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
    theHeader.classList.add("fullscreen");
    $('.nav').hide();
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.footer').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.nav {
  background: #ffcc00;
}
.header {
  background: #ccff00;
}
.content {
  background: #00ccff;
}
.footer {
  background: #cc00ff;
}
.fullscreen {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body id="test">
  <div class="nav">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="footer">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```